# Integrity constraint violation/foreign key constraint fails

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database, relationship

I have the following integrity constraint violation where a foreign key constraint fails. Any ideas appreciated.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
> update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`go-motoring`.`promotion_products`, CONSTRAINT
> `promotion_products_product_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`)
> REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into
> `promotion_products` (`product_id`, `promotion_id`) values (0, 3))

**Product Model**

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(EcommerceCategory::class, 'product_categories', 
        'product_id', 'ecommerce_category_id');
}
```

**Promotion Model**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'promotion_products', 
        'promotion_id', 'product_id');
}
```

**Promotion Controller**

```
$params = $request->except(['_token', 'select_product']);
$promotion = new Promotion($params);
$promotion->save();
//category sync
$data['product_ids'] = $request->select_product; //convert product ids in array
$promotion->products()->sync($data['product_ids']); //sync (insert & update)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[solution. because 0 value exist in incoming data. 0 not save as a foreign key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESjpH.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to resolve the issue?